# AngularJS - how do you know when angular has finished processing a page?

Tags: angularjs

How to know when all interpolation and processing on a given page has been completed?

```
            compile: function (tElement, tAttrs) {
                return function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    element.html(tpl);
                    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                };
            },
```

This is not synchronous.  If there are {{stuff}} and ng-repeat="..." etc... they will not all be guaranteed to be completed when the link function returns.

I need a way to know when the page has rendered and there's no more directives to process so that I can then use #hashes to navigate to elements created on the page by angular.  (using $anchorScroll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
  // ....
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a directive in angular for this very specific reason ; ngCloak.

> The ngCloak directive is used to prevent the Angular html template
>   from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled)
>   form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid
>   the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display.

Doc @ https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Similar Question on Quora; ***How do I hide a div with AngularJS until ng-repeat has finished processing?*** @ https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-hide-a-div-with-AngularJS-until-ng-repeat-has-finished-processing

[image]

This is another way to do it, but I prefer to use angular directive.

```
<li ng-repeat="opt in menuItems" my-custom-repeat-listener> </li>
```

and then on the directive something sort of like

```
if(scope.$last) { /*fire event or etc to show the list items*/ }
```